# Is it possible to import a vue component file within a lifecycle (beforeCreate)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Actually I think that this is not possible. But would to ask it anyways. I am trying to activate some components from the DB. So I get a array list of some active components within the component "methods". Because I cant access the list variable at the beginning of the file, I want to import these components files within beforeCreate() lifecycle when the array list variable is ready.

Basically something like:

```
beforeCreate() {
        import testComp from './testComp.vue';
}
```

What do you think would there be a way to accomplish such a thing?

Comment: sounds like what you want is [Async-Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components)

Comment: @JacobGoh  Yes you are right seems like some kind of Async-Components could be my solution. But how can I use that within a loop in the lifecycle beforeCreate?

Comment: after reading your question more closely, i think you don't really need async component. What you need is how to handle the component when a certain variable isn't available yet. (variable containing data from ajax, i assume) The general way is just to use something like `v-if="arrayVariable!==null"` so that it wont render before `arrayVariable` is ready

Comment: If you need to dynamically decide which component to use, then you can use <component is="your-component-name"></component>

Comment: Exactly @JacobGoh. Right now I am using it as you said <componen v-if="arrayVariable!==null"> Together with v-for to loop the components. This way I can decide wether to activate or disable the component/s. But I need to import (each) the componentFileName.vue file manually   in order to call/run it without errors.

Comment: `import (each) the componentFileName.vue file manually in order to call/run it without errors` that's the way it's supposed to work =]

Comment: For example if I add a new component (name path ect.) to the DB then I still have to add the component files manually to the file. But I want them to be imported automatically via the component array I got from the DB.

Comment: I see @JacobGoh. When that is the limit/rule then I have no other chance I guess. Then I will write down all existing components manually and call only the activated ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly import a component in `beforeCreate`. Straight from the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components)

```
beforeCreate: function () {
  this.$options.components.TreeFolderContents = require('./tree-folder-contents.vue').default
}
```

Comment: Actually this solution works when I write it manually. But when I want to make the loop, this time I cant get the data (coming from database) from props (because it is asynchronous).